# How to obtain maximum likelihood estimate of the median of survival time from the R output of a survival regression?

Tags: r

I've been given this R output:

```
> summary(SurvregModel.1) 

Call: survreg(formula = Surv(tempo, status) ~ sexo, data = melanoma,      dist = "exponential") 

                   Value  Std. Error    z      p (Intercept)        9.237      0.189  48.9   0.0000 sexo[T.masculino] -0.662      0.265  -2.5   0.0125 

Scale fixed at 1  

Exponential distribution Loglik(model)= -564.3   Loglik(intercept only)= -567.4  Chisq= 6.15 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.013  Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5  n= 205
```

From this I need to obtain the maximum likelihood estimate of the median of the survival time, yet do not know how to interpret the given coefficients or the other values in the lower part of the output. I've read the R help of this function and it didn't answer this.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A reproducible example would help...

Comment: This is the only output I'm given. I just want to know what can I interpret from this

Comment: I was asking for your input. The way you are asking, the only chance is, when somebody is working with this package...